# knockout.js data binding under <template> is not happening

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

Hi I'm trying to do databinding as given under:

```
<!-- ko if: input() == "table" -->
        <div style ="width:80% class="oj-flex" data-bind="if: visible()">
                <oj-collapsible expanded="true" :id="{{'expand_'+id}}">
                    <h5 class="oj-header-border" slot="header"><span data-bind="text: label" style="font-weight:bold"></span></h5>
                    <div class="oj-flex-item">
                        <oj-table :id="{{'table_'+id}}" aria-label='List'
                            scroll-policy='loadMoreOnScroll'
                            scroll-policy-options='{"fetchSize": 100}'
                            data='[[dataprovider]]'
                            display="grid"
                            columns='[[columns]]'
                            style='width:100%;height: 400px'>
                            <template slot="operationHeaderTemplate">
                                <!-- ko if: createButtonEnabled()-->
                                <oj-button class="oj-button-sm" chroming='half' disabled="{{readonly}}" data-bind="click: $context.$module.addItem" style='vertical-align: middle'>
                                    <img src="css/images/ico-plus-circle.svg" alt="Add Icon" height="16px" width="16px" style="vertical-align: middle;padding-right:0px"> Add
                                </oj-button>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            </template>
                        </oj-table>
                     </div>
                </oj-collapsible>
           </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

But  it is not working. Any idea how to incorporate this

Comment: there is no closing double quote for the style attribute on the second line.  `<div style="width:80% class="oj-flex" ... ` etc should be `<div style="width:80%" class="oj-flex" ... `

Comment: What errors are you seeing in the console?